# Reading word by word including following whitespaces

Tags: c, string, input, whitespace, scanf

Good morning guys, I have a problem with input in C. What I want to do is read a word including with all the whitespaces that are following it up to the next word
for example:

```
Hello_______Hi  // consider _ to be a whitespace

Hello_______
```

I haven't found a way to make `scanf` do the trick, neither `strtok`. I am all out of ideas and any general tips would be great! thank you

Comment: Show what have you tried, also show what do you want to achieve by giving some input and what do you expect to be the output.

Comment: If you want to be able to read the second word too, then you have to read the complete line and do the parsing yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with `scanf`

```
char *a;
printf ("\n Enter a string: ");
scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &a);
printf ("\n string: '%s'\n\n", a);
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/scanfws

 Enter a string: Hello     Hi

 string: 'Hello     Hi'
```

To not have `scanf` allocate:

```
char a[30];
printf ("\n Enter a string: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", a);
printf ("\n string: '%s'\n\n", a);
```

Comment: Hmm, if I use the exact code I get an instant crash

Comment: That is not possible. Are you on Window or Linux?

Comment: I am on windows, using codeblocks to edit the code and compile using gcc compiler, it works like a charm without the allocation of scanf. Thank you!